# Input Tag, Why is my javascript code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with my project on javascript. I want to make tag input

[image]

It must be a tag after I clicked comma, but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me to solve this?

Here's the javascript and html code. I've tried this code in other project, and it worked but not for this project. The repositary is right. I wonder which one is my problem.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function(el){
    let hiddenInput = document.getElementsById('hdn'),
    mainInput = document.getElementsById('inp');
    tags = [];


    mainInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
        let enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(',');
        if (enteredTags.length > 1){
            enteredTags.forEach(function(t){
                let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
                if (filteredTag.length > 0)
                    addTag(filteredTag);
            });
            mainInput.value = '';
        }

    });

    el.appendChild(mainInput);
    el.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    addTag('hello');

    function addTag (text){
        let tag = {
            text: text,
            element: document.createElement('span'),
        };

        tag.element.classList.add('tag');
        tag.element.textContent = tag.text;

        let closeBtn = document.createElement('span');
        closeBtn.classList.add('close');
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            removeTag(tags.indexOf(tag));
        });
        tag.element.appendChild(closeBtn);

        tags.push(tag); 
        el.insertBefore(tag.element, mainInput);

        refreshTags();
    }

    function removeTag (index){
        let tag = tags[index];
        tags.splice(index,1);
        el.removeChild(tag.element);
        refreshTags();

    }

    function refreshTags (){

    }

    function filterTag (tag){
        return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, '').trim().replace(/\W+/g, '-');

    }

});
```

```html
@push('style')
  <link href="{{asset('/css/tag.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
@endpush
@push('script')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/js/tag.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
...

    <div class="field">
        <label>Tag</label>
        <div class="tags-input" >
            <input class="main-input" type="text" id="inp" name="tag2" placeholder="Contoh: akreditasi, banding, TUK mandiri">
            <input type="hidden" name="tags-input" id="hdn" >
   </div>
        <span class="help-block">Gunakan tanda koma sebagai pemisah</span>
```

...

Comment: Please rewrite your explanation to make it clearer and simpler.

Comment: With 'Why is my code not working' in the title your question will get low attention. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are there any console errors? If yes, try to fix them first.

Comment: @AkashBhardwaj I already found the solution. It's my mistake, I forgot to write the </div> in my html. Thanks